# Virtualenvwrapper, can I get rid of it from Terminal and my Sublime Text?

Tags: macos, terminal, text-editor

I have an MBP latest OS running, I tried to follow a guide to install VirtualEnvWrapper a few weeks ago, not too sure why.

But I keep getting this error when opening terminal and its quite annoying, how to get rid?
http://puu.sh/nSu82/fcb2f5291a.png

and in my sublime text I see it too:
http://puu.sh/nSu9F/2cc43f46a0.png

How can I fix this?

Edit: I also tried 
sed -n '3p' $HOME/.bash_profile

and got

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh

Comment: It looks like you need to remove line 3 of your `.bash_profile` which contains a reference to `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh`. Edit your post with the results of this command `sed -n '3p' $HOME/.bash_profile`

Comment: what do you mean by edit my post. I typed in what you stated and I received this in response:

sed -n '3p' $HOME/.bash_profile
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh

Comment: I now have a screen image of .bash_profile itself:
http://puu.sh/nSwNN/40d3031c44.png

Comment: Remove the offending line and the error message will go away. Then try to reinstall VirtualEnv following the guide (if you really need it).